# Laravel - eager load only part of a relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

In the Eloquent query builder we can specify load a relation with the `width('relation')` for example the `User` model could have a method like this

```
    public function teamsWithMembers(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'team_memberships', 'user_id', 'team_code')->with('members');
    }
```

where the `Team` model has a relation like this

```
    public function members(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'team_memberships', 'team_code', 'user_id')->withPivot('role');
    }
```

This loads the whole `User` model for each member in each team of the original `User` model, and it seems I can only filter the amount of data for each member in each team after the query is run, which seems like a waste of resources. My question is what to do when we don't need the whole model, only parts of it, eg. only the name of each member.

Comment: One of the answers on the linked duplicate shows how to do this, as does [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns). Syntax is `::with('relationship:column_a,column_b,...')`, but make sure to include the FK constriant, otherwise the relationship will return as an empty `Collection` or `null`

Comment: There's also logic to hide/show specific columns when converting the Model/Relationship to JSON: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json